# Why activity works in an application but doesn't in another application?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, chat

So here's my problem.
I'm working on implementing a chat application though a server/client network, using sockets, between 2 smartphones.

My code used as an application, works fine to send messages between the 2 smartphones.

But, i would like to put this code, in a different application and using all my code as an activity. 
And here... it doesn't work anymore.

I've copied/pasted all the code of my first chat application in new java classes in the new application, pasted the parts of the Android manifest as well. Only one device seems to connect to the other.

Would you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you also copy the imports?  If you didn't and tried to find the imports using your short cut keys, it is not uncommon to mistakenly select the wrongs ones.  Another thought, try cleaning your project after a major copy paste effort.

Comment: Could you be more specific about _how_ it doesn't work? What errors do you get? Does it compile?

Comment: Hello N8sBug, thanks for your answer.
 I've actually just found the solution. My first application and my new one have a different package name. Even implementing the classes of the first application, in the new application and changing the package name at the top of the files, it didn't work. Actually, i think communication between 2 applications with different package names doesn't work. Or i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @Mylo Raf You can communicate between applications, but you need to register them and, although I don't know personally, I think you may need a permission added.  Glad you got it fixed though.

Comment: @vhu, The server received the connection with the client, though the sending of the messages didn't work. It was like a "one way" network kind of.

Comment: u might be calling these classes in your new app activities , getting any error ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are copying the xml files in the layout folder including any drawables you used in the first project.

Remember this when calling these elements in the classes (in the onCreate method if you are using an activity or in the onCreateView method if you are using fragments).

This should resolve your issue.